# How can I programmatically obtain a list of trackers on website?

Tags: javascript, python, firefox-addon, tracker

Is there a way to use a programming language, say Python or Javascript, to obtain a list of trackers on a website? Does a tracker have some kind of marker that can be detected programmatically?

Comment: Please define "tracker"!

Comment: A tracker is a script that collects information about a user's browsing behavior on the site in which the tracker is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly could create an extension for your browser of choice that reads the page and watches for cross domain requests. If you're looking for something very situational you could always just watch the network tab in your browser's development tools. We would need more information on the "why" before you'd get a good direction recommendation.